# What is better join, in or in with join

Tags: postgresql, join

I have these tables:

calls: rows [ 'created_at', 'user_id']

users: rows ['id', 'username']

And I need to get all user without calls from date:
How can I get it? Or what way is better and why?

I know three ways:

first:

```
SELECT id 
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM calls where calls.created_at >= date)
```

second(I think it is not right, but I am not sure):

```
SELECT id
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN calls
   ON calls.user_id = users.id
WHERE calls.created_at >= date AND calls.user_id ISNULL
```

last:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM calls
   INNER JOIN users AS call_users
      ON call_users.id = users.id
   WHERE calls.created_at >= date
```

DB: PostgreSQL

Comment: Better according to what criteria?

Comment: Those queries will return different results as you are using a >= for two of them and a <= for the third. That will mean users created on that date in the where clause will not br in two of the result sets but will be in the third.

Comment: If you want to know which one is most efficient, check [the execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE)

Comment: Not only your "negation" of `>=` is wrong, that'll be `<` **not** `<=`, the first query will also include users, that are not in `calls` at all (or with a creation time of null), whereas the second will only select users (I just guess that's the target for all three as the second and third also miss a `FROM` (the third even twice)), that are in `calls` with a not null creation time matching the inequality.

Comment: The join in the third query makes not much sense to me. It might reduce the set to the `NOT IN` a little if there are users, that are in `calls` but not in `users` but those won't be selected from `users` in the outer query either, as they don't exist. And I guess you might be best of with a `NOT EXISTS` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is specifically meant to express simple queries more or less like you would ask them as a question in English. For instance, your question is like:

> "What are all the `id` from `users` that have no
>   associated call in `calls` with a `created_date` greater or equal than date $1 ?"

SQL translation:

```
SELECT id FROM users
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM calls WHERE call.user_id=users.id AND created_date >= $1
  );
```

It's a rather direct translation except maybe for SELECTing `1`, which is an arbitrary value.

There is no reason to assume that PostgreSQL would produce a non-optimal execution plan for this query. The optimizer is certainly smart enough for that kind of queries. In general if there's a straightforward way to express your query, there's no reason to pretend to be smarter than the optimizer.

When you doubt that the optimizer found the best possible plan (say for more complex queries), you can start from the output of EXPLAIN to figure out if/why it's not optimal and typically try to improve the query by trial and error.

If you want to compare how different variants of the same query are planned, compare the outputs of EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the queries.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions is a good start too.